# Por que no se cumple el elif en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, condiciones, else

estoy intentando resolver esto:

me solicita que si el numero que se ingresa es impar muestre: raro, enseguida si es par y es mayor que dos y menor que 5 muestre: no es raro, enseguida si es mayor que 6 y menor que 20 y es par muestre: raro  y por ultimo si es mayor que 20 y es par muestre: no es raro.

Mi problema radica en que cuando ingreso 18 sale: no es raro. de igual manera el 20.

```
    import math
    import os
    import random
    import re
    import sys

    if n % 2 != 0:
        print("raro")
    elif n > 2 & n < 5 & n % 2 == 0:
        print("no es raro")
    elif n > 6 & n < 20 & n % 2 == 0:
        print("raro")
    elif n >= 20 & n % 2 == 0:
        print("no es raro")
```

Comment: El operador `&` es [un operador a nivel de bits](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators). Creo que lo que tu pretendes es el **Y** lógico: `and`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En python el operador lógico para la Y se llama `and`, por lo que, tomando por ejemplo una de tus expresiones (la del segundo `elif`) deberías haber escrito:

```
n > 6 and n < 20 and n % 2 == 0
```

Este operador, además, tiene la menor precedencia entre todos los que aparecen, lo que significa que será el último en ser evaluado, y esa es la razón por la que no se requieren paréntesis. Pero si ponemos paréntesis para mayor claridad, la anterior expresión equivale a:

```
(n > 6) and (n < 20) and (n % 2 == 0)
```

### ¿Qué pasó en tu caso?

Ahora bien, tú usaste `&`:

```
n > 6 & n < 20 & n % 2 == 0
```

¿por qué ésto no produjo un error en el intérprete pero en cambio no funcionó como esperabas? La razón es que `&` es otro operador de python que no tiene que ver con la lógica booleana, sino con operaciones entre enteros a nivel de bits.

Para enteder más exactamente qué hacía tu expresión, hay que comenzar por decir que, a diferencia de `and`, `&` tiene la prioridad más alta entre los operadores que aparecen en esa línea (salvo por `%` que la tiene aún mayor), es decir, será evaluado antes que los comparadores `>`, `<` o `==`. Por lo que si pongo paréntesis para que se vea más claro, tu expresión equivale a esta otra:

```
n > (6 & n) < (20 & (n % 2)) == 0
```

¿Qué es este galimatías? Como he dicho `&` es una operación entre enteros. Imagina que n=18 como en el ejemplo que no te funciona. ¿Qué está calculando Python realmente en la línea anterior?

- Primero calcula `6 & n` que en el caso de n=18 sale 2 (¿por qué? Ya lo explico al final)
- Después calcula `n % 2` que sale 0, y por fin `20 & 0`, que sale 0
- Por tanto, para n=18 la línea anterior equivale a:

  ```py
  18 > 2 < 0 == 0
  ```
- Tenemos por tanto una expresión en la que se están comparando un montón de cosas con otras, y para evaluar eso python mira si todas las comparaciones se cumplen *a la vez*. Es decir, debe cumplirse que 18>2, y que 2<0 y que 0==0.
- Ya que una de ellas no se cumple (2<0 es falsa) el resultado final es `False` y por eso no entraba por ese `elif`.

**NOTA FINAL** ¿Qué operación hace `&` entre dos enteros? Lo que hace es considerar los bits que constituyen esos enteros y hacer la operación AND entre cada pareja de bits.

Es decir, `6 & 18` produce 2, porque si ponemos 6 y 18 en binario uno debajo de otro vemos:

```
 6 --> 00000110
18 --> 00010010
```

Y ahora, haciendo la operación and en vertical entre cada pareja de bits el resultado será 1 sólo donde haya dos 1 en vertical. Por tanto el resultado sale 00000010 que es 2.

Ya puedes ver también por qué `20 & 0` sale 0 (de hecho `&` de cualquier cosa con 0 va a salir 0).

## Bonus

Eso de las múltiples comparaciones en la misma línea está permitido por python en vez de ser un error de sintaxis, para permitirte escribir cosas más lógicas y útiles como esta: `0 < x < 100`, que te sirve para evaluar si un número dado está dentro de un cierto rango. Python comprueba que sean ciertas *a la vez*, `0 < x` y `x < 100`

Y esto te puede servir a tí para simplificar un poco más tus expresiones, ya que puedes escribir:

```
    if n % 2 != 0:
        print("raro")
    elif 2 < n < 5:
        print("no es raro")
    elif 6 < n < 20:
        print("raro")
    elif 20 <= n:
        print("no es raro")
```

Fíjate que no se necesita verificar que `n % 2 == 0` en cada una de las ramas `elif`, ya que si estamos en una de esas ramas es porque la condición del `if` no se ha cumplido, y por tanto necesariamente `n` es par.

**Observación**: ¿Qué ha de suceder en los casos en que n es 2 o 6? Parece que no está bien definido. En esos casos no se va a cumplir ninguna de las condiciones. Yo sospecho que tal vez en lugar de `2 < n` haya que poner `2 <= n`, (y análogamente `6 <= n`) para que estos casos queden también cubiertos, pero el enunciado no lo deja claro.